# Refused to apply style from 'URL' because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: spring, mime-types, tomcat9

I recently upgraded my web application from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 9. Prior to the upgrade, the application was working correctly, but now I'm encountering an error related to the MIME type of my CSS files. Specifically, I see the error message:

> Refused to apply style from 'URL' because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I've tried adding the following mapping to my web.xml file:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

But the error persists. It's worth noting that I'm running the application locally on my machine. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

The web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!-- Listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- filters -->
    <!-- Reads request input using UTF-8 encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <!-- Filter Mappings -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Context parameters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>apps.web.common.conf.SpringConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Atmosphere -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>feeds</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.resumeOnBroadcast</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useWebSocket</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.useStream</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>feeds</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/index.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>png</extension>
        <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ico</extension>
        <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The file paths for the CSS are correct and I get 200 code in the browser. But I cannot find any Content-Type in the Response headers.

Also, I have cleared the browser's caches.

I am using IntelliJ.